# Selenium get value python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in using selenium, I would like to get this value of the line highlighted. While I am using the get attribute function, it pop up an error ."TypeError: get_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'". How can I solve it or any part is missing?

```
def HSI_realtimeprice():

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Equity-Index/Hang-Seng-Index-(HSI)/Hang-Seng-Index-Options?sc_lang=zh-HK#&product=HSI')
hsi_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ls"]').get_attribute()
print(hsi_price)
```

HSI_realtimeprice()

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should input the attributes of what you want to achieve.

```
hsi_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ls"]').get_attribute('insert_here')
```

And it looks like you want to get the text, use `innerHTML`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ls"]').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Although that can also be achieved with `.text`:

```
hsi_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="ls"]').text
```

Comment: @AnsonChan Glad to hear, feel free :) to upvote this answer with hit button `^` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hsi_price.text` if you mean to extract "12,639.39"

`get_attribute()` should be used when you wanna extract attributes like `href`, `src`, etc.

For this element

```
<img src="http://example.com/my-image.img"/>
```

the code

```
element.get_attribute('src')
```

gets you `http://example.com/my-image.img`